# How Would i Store OCR text into SQLite database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, ocr, text-recognition

I am developing a routine app to store the data of Routine posted on a notice board based on a keyword entered. For example, if you are from group A (should be certain unique keyword), Just enter the Keyword and Scan the piece of Paper and it will store the data from it to your phone.So that's the Concept.I have gotten to the point where my phone can detect text.But i am stuck on storing the data.Can any one help?
PS: I am new to android development..So please Elaborate it a bit..

Answer (score 0):

first things first, this question is very broad and asks for a final solution, not really about a problem. You should learn more about Android development with tutorials and classes you can find free online.

Now, to answer some part of it, here follows a class on GitHub that accesses the database and persists some things:

https://github.com/ravi8x/AndroidSQLite/blob/master/app/src/main/java/info/androidhive/sqlite/database/DatabaseHelper.java

You have to pay attention to the code in GitHub, since it uses additional classes you can browse. I hope this is enough to help you a bit.